# IGFX display driver stops responding Win10, Nvidia

Tags: windows-10, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

Have a user with an HP Envy Laptop running Win10. Seemingly randomly, he is getting errors that the igfx display driver "has stopped responding and has recovered" after Windows restarts the driver through performance monitoring.

I've been to [the HP help file](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01317954) and NVidia website about this error and gone through each of the recommendations including reducing visual effects, updating the driver, checking for certain programs that use GPU to be causing the issue, installed Windows updates, etc. I've also run check disk

So far the user has been able to reproduce the problem with just Internet Explorer running and no other programs. There are a lot of services running (normal for win10, I guess?), but I don't know where to go from here to diagnose the issue. This is a new laptop, and the previous laptop ran all of the same software for 7 years without issue, including Win10 for 6 months.

Comment: igfx is the Intel HD driver. update this driver

Comment: @magicandre1981 [Slaps forehead] You mean to tell me updating an Nvidia driver would not fix a problem with an Intel driver?!? haha thanks, I thought about it after I wrote the question, I'm not sure why I never made the connection that the Intel would not be driving Nvidia. You have confirmed my brain fart.